# Cannot import langchain.vectorstores.FAISS, only langchain_community.vectorstores.faiss

Tags: python, py-langchain, faiss

I am in the process of building a RAG like the one in this [Video](https://youtu.be/dXxQ0LR-3Hg?si=BtBrdI7eRb15hPzW&t=2065). However, I cannot import FAISS like this.

```
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS

LangChainDeprecationWarning: Importing vector stores from langchain is deprecated. Importing from langchain will no longer be supported as of langchain==0.2.0. Please import from langchain-community instead:

`from langchain_community.vectorstores import faiss`.
```

However, it is possible to import faiss:

```
from langchain_community.vectorstores import faiss
```

But with this it is not possible to call faiss.from_text().

```
vectorstore = faiss.from_texts(text=text_chunks, embeddings=embeddings)

AttributeError: module 'langchain_community.vectorstores.faiss' has no attribute 'from_texts'
```

Is it no longer possible to call .from_text() with the current one? I didn't find anything about this in the documentation.

Python=3.10.13

Comment: you need to use `FAISS.from_documents` , i.e. read the text into documents as that is much aligned with langchain overall strategy to load the documents.

Comment: Unfortunately, faiss.from_documents() cannot be called either.

`AttributeError: module 'langchain_community.vectorstores.faiss' has no attribute 'from_documents'`

Comment: Why do you have this tagged `faiss` and not `py-langchain`? It only applies to people using specifically _langchain bindings_ and is completely irrelevant to other faiss users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was for me to importing the FAISS class directly from the langchain.vectorstores.faiss module and then using the from_documents method.

```
from langchain_community.vectorstores.faiss import FAISS
```

I had importing the faiss module itself, rather than the FAISS class from the langchain.vectorstores.faiss module. The from_documents method is a class method of the FAISS class, not a function of the faiss module.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll have to import the langchain community package like so:
`from langchain_community.vectorstores.faiss import FAISS`

Then, you can use `vectorstore = FAISS.from_texts(texts = text_chunks, embedding = embeddings)`

Works as far I know.